# How to delete rows under a specific condition in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have to delete rows from my df in relation to a particular condition.

i have a simple df

```
sentID   partner  sentence
  A        B        C
  A        B        D
  B        C        E
  B        C        F
  B        A        S
```

and I want to delete the ones in which sentID & partner are equal and **in the same time** the sentID is not associated to another partner value. (i.e. The specific sentID does not appear with the same partner value only.) 
Otherwise, I have to keep the row.

```
sentID   partner  sentence
  B        C        E
  B        C        F
  B        A        S
```

In the output example, the rows containing sentID A were deleted because it appears with partner B only. SentID B was kept because it appears with partner C and A.

How could I do?

thank you for your suggestions!

Comment: What do you mean by "not associated" ?

Comment: @zx8754 The specific sentID does not appear with the same partner value only. In the output example, the rows containing sentID A were deleted because it appears with partner B only. SentID B was kept because it appears with partner C and A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```r
df <- data.frame(sentID = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
                  partner = c("B", "B", "C", "C", "A"))

df
#>   sentID partner
#> 1      A       B
#> 2      A       B
#> 3      B       C
#> 4      B       C
#> 5      B       A

library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(sentID) %>% filter(length(unique(partner)) > 1)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#> # Groups:   sentID [1]
#>   sentID partner
#>   <fctr>  <fctr>
#> 1      B       C
#> 2      B       C
#> 3      B       A
```

<sup>Created on 2019-01-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>